# How to get the next sequence key in LeveDB in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, leveldb

I am using LevelDB with string+number keys in a Hyperledger Fabric project. Example keys:

LA000, LA001, LA002
TS001, TS002, TS003

How should I execute a query in HyperLedger fabric chaincode on the state database (levelDB) for example, to know the next TS... number to use?

Do I need to execute a sorted key based query and get the key value for the last entry, and increment it to get the next key or is there a better approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A better approach is to create a separate key for each prefix string and store the last number used.  This will be atomic in nature and will prevent accidentally reusing the same key.